# Java detecting directories

Tags: java, directory

Good afternoon.

I'm currently maintaining an application that needs to parse directories.
The application uses `File.isDirectory()` to detect whether a given path is a directory or a file, then recursively fetches all the files and sub-directories contained.

This works, unless the directory name contains spaces, so a path like `C:\Foo\Bar` detects both `Foo` and `Bar` as directories, which is the desired behaviour; but a path such as `C:\F oo\Bar` does not: `File.isDirectory()` returns `false` (as does `File.isFile()`) on such a path.
On the other hand, `File.isAbsolute()` returns `true` - so it's an absolute path, but neither a file nor a directory, according to the File library.

Is there any workaround? Any alternatives to detect whether a given path is a directory? Or am I doomed to running this application only on directories with no spaces in them?

Thank you for your attention.

Edit: the File is created by a rather tortuous process involving a String being converted to a File back to a String and back to a File over 5-6 method calls (not my code).
Anyway, I've located the root of the issue, I think. I'll fix it.

Should I delete this question? I don't see it being very useful to future users.

Comment: Please post some code - how are you creating the `File` object?

Comment: It has nothing to do with spaces. Java File class knows how to deal with spaces, it must be your code. Try to look if you are calling trim somewhere.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand, you have a folder named “F oo” (with a space in the name) on you C drive? What does `File.exists()` say?

Comment: It’s much easier to help you if you give us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: java.io.File is obsolete.  The [java.nio.file package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) will give you more reliable results.  It also has a number of useful `walk` and `walkFileTree` methods for doing recursive file processing.

Comment: Obsolete? `File` has some limitations compared to `java.nio.file.Path` and friends, but the documentation doesn’t mention it being obsolete, and we’re many that are still happy to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it in Max os.  everything is ok

```
File dir = new File("/Users/JinQi/Downloads/is space/foo");
File dir1 = new File("/Users/JinQi/Downloads/is\\ space/foo");
System.out.println(dir.isDirectory()); // true
System.out.println(dir1.isDirectory()); // false
```

why I tried `is\\ space` is that I found that unix terminal show path with space in this way.

maybe you can try this way in windows.

Answer (score -1):

today I'v written a code which populates a JTable with files' paths. Hope it helps.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class LeftPanel extends JPanel {

 private JTable table;
 private NavigationPanel backAndDriverPanel;

 private String[] columns = { "Path", "Size", "Last Modified" };
 private File file;
 private File[] filesNames;

 private final String DIR = "C:/";

 public LeftPanel() {

  Dimension dimension = getPreferredSize();
  dimension.width = 640;
  setPreferredSize(dimension);
  setLayout(new BorderLayout());

  // CREATING COMPONENTS
  table = new JTable();
  backAndDriverPanel = new NavigationPanel();

  table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
  table.setFocusable(false);
  table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);

  JScrollPane tableScroll = new JScrollPane(table);

  // ADDING COMPONENTS TO PANEL
  add(tableScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  add(backAndDriverPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

  createTableModel();

 }

 public void createTableModel() {

  // DATE FORMAT
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

  file = new File(DIR);

  filesNames = file.listFiles();

  DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
  model.setColumnIdentifiers(columns);

  // LIST OF ROWS
  Object[] row = new Object[3];
  for (int i = 0; i < filesNames.length; i++) {

   row[0] = filesNames[i].getAbsolutePath();
   row[1] = filesNames[i].length();

   // CONVERTING FROM MILISECONDS TO NORMAL DATE
   row[2] = sdf.format(filesNames[i].lastModified());

   model.addRow(row);
  }

  // SETING EDITABLE TO FALSE
  for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {

   Class<?> col_clas = table.getColumnClass(i);
   table.setDefaultEditor(col_clas, null);
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: I fail to see how this solves the problem of correctly identifying a directory with a space in the name as a directory.